# Protocol switching successfully or not

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have the following code snippet, that does not compile:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.Done
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  import system.dispatcher

  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes
  val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println(message.text)
  }


  // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
  val sourceSocketFlow = RestartSource.withBackoff(
    minBackoff = 3.seconds,
    maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
    randomFactor = 0.2,
    maxRestarts = 3
  ) { () =>
    Source.tick(2.seconds, 2.seconds, TextMessage("Hello world!!!"))
        .viaMat(Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/")))(Keep.right)
  }
  // the materialized value is a tuple with
  // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
  // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
  // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
  val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
    sourceSocketFlow
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
    .run()

  // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
  // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
  val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
      Future.successful(Done)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
    }
  }

  connected.onComplete(println)
  closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))

}
```

The problem here is, that:

```
  // the materialized value is a tuple with
  // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
  // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
  // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
  val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
    sourceSocketFlow
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
    .run()
```

does not return `Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]` at first position in the tuple but instead it returns `NotUsed`.

The question is, how to get the return type `Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]` to identify, that the connection was successfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RestartSource#withBackoff](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/ef3a19b5d0e970501cde4d78168cce8b940a56ef/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/RestartSource.scala#L77) accepts a `sourceFactory` of a type `() => Source[T, _]` and returns a new source of a type `Source[T, NotUsed]`. So it's not possible to extract the materialized value from the wrapped source. That's probably because the materialized value will be different on every RestartSource restart.

> The question is, how to get the return type Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] to identify, that the connection was successful.

If you want to check if the connection was established, and if WebSockets handshake succeeded, you can prematerialize the source using [Source#preMaterialize](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#source-pre-materialization). A slightly modified version of your code would look like the following:

```
val sourceSocketFlow: Source[Message, NotUsed] = RestartSource.withBackoff(
  minBackoff = 3.seconds,
  maxBackoff = 30.seconds,
  randomFactor = 0.2,
  maxRestarts = 3
) { () =>
  val (response, source) = Source
    .tick(2.seconds, 2.seconds, TextMessage("Hello world!!!"))
    .viaMat(Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://mockbin.org/bin/82b160d4-6c05-4943-908a-a15122603e20")))(Keep.right).preMaterialize()

  response.onComplete {
    case Failure(e) ⇒
      println(s"Connection failed")

    case Success(value) ⇒
      if (value.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        println("Server supports websockets")
      } else {
        println("Server does not support websockets")
      }
  }

  source
}
```

In case the connection fails, or [websocket handshake fails](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/f57ec755a9107a8c1c25412ecde3149a91261e7c/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/ws/Handshake.scala#L260), you don't have to do anything. Both cases will be handled by RestartSource.